# connected components in an undirected graph in c++

Tags: c++, graph

I was searching for a c++ code to find connected components in an undirected graph. I have a big matrix which is called "directed". Its elements are zero or one. directed(i,j)=1 means i vertice has a directed link to j vertice. I want to find the number of different groups created by directly or indirectly connection of vertices and size of the groups. Below code takes connected vertices and print different groups' elements in different lines. 
Knowing directed matrix, could anyone help me to find the number of groups and size of each of them? This is the code:

```
// C++ program to print connected components in
// an undirected graph
#include<iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

// Graph class represents a undirected graph
// using adjacency list representation
int input(istream& in=cin)
{
int x;
in >> x;
return x;
}


class Graph
{
int V;    // No. of vertices

// Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
list<int> *adj;

// A function used by DFS
void DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]);
public:
Graph(int V);   // Constructor
void addEdge(int v, int w);
void connectedComponents();
};

// Method to print connected components in an
// undirected graph
void Graph::connectedComponents()
{
// Mark all the vertices as not visited
bool *visited = new bool[V];
for(int v = 0; v < V; v++)
    visited[v] = false;

for (int v=0; v<V; v++)
{
     if (visited[v] == false)
       {
        // print all reachable vertices
        // from v
        DFSUtil(v, visited);

        cout << "\n";
       }
    }
}

void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[])
{
// Mark the current node as visited and print it
visited[v] = true;
cout << v << " ";

// Recur for all the vertices
// adjacent to this vertex
list<int>::iterator i;
for(i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
    if(!visited[*i])
        DFSUtil(*i, visited);
}

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
this->V = V;
adj = new list<int>[V];
}

// method to add an undirected edge
void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
adj[v].push_back(w);
adj[w].push_back(v);
}

// Drive program to test above
int main()
{
int directed[2][2];

 directed[0][0]=1;
 directed[0][1]=0;
 directed[0][2]=0;
 directed[1][1]=1;
 directed[1][0]=1;
 directed[1][2]=1;
 directed[2][1]=0;
 directed[2][2]=0;
 directed[2][0]=1;
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Pro Tip: `adj = new list<int>[V];` - not a good idea... You should change the type of `adj` to `std::vector<std::list<int>>` and simply initialize it in your *member-initializer-list*. Again, `std::list`... mehh... if you don not need `std::list` iterator invalidation guarantees, use a `std::vector` instead

Comment: The same with other pointers (like e.g. `visited` in the `connectedComponents` function). Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Could any of you provide a complete answer, please? @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please provide a runnable answer (x4)

Sure:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7254a9cc5562a123)</kbd>**

```
// C++ program to print connected components in
// an undirected graph
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>

// Graph class represents a undirected graph
// using adjacency list representation
class Graph {
    using G = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;
    using Component = int;
    using Mapping = std::map<G::vertex_descriptor, Component>;
    G g;

  public:
    Graph(int V) : g(V) {}
    void addEdge(int v, int w);
    void connectedComponents();
};

// Method to print connected components in an
// undirected graph
void Graph::connectedComponents() {
    Mapping mappings;
    int n = boost::connected_components(g, boost::make_assoc_property_map(mappings));

    for (Component c = 0; c<n; ++c) {
        std::cout << "component " << c << ":";

        for (auto& mapping : mappings)
            if (mapping.second == c) std::cout << " " << mapping.first;

        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) {
    boost::add_edge(v, w, g);
}

int main() {
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram
    Graph g(5); // 5 vertices numbered from 0 to 4
    g.addEdge(1, 0);
    g.addEdge(2, 3);
    g.addEdge(3, 4);

    std::cout << "Following are connected components \n";
    g.connectedComponents();
}
```

Prints

```
Following are connected components 
component 0: 0 1
component 1: 2 3 4
```

Comment: [Could you please provide a runnable answer which uses 'directed' matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46659904/connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph-in-c/46662754#comment80269070_46660136) - I'm sorry I might not have fully addressed your concerns: [now correctly adapted for directed adjacency matrix](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c579393eea3d5a14)

Comment: Could you please add an optional "directed" matrix to make your answer runnable? Thre is an error boost/graph/adjacency_matrix.hpp: No such file or directory
 right now

Comment: There's live demos. They run. The output is right there live. In case you don't want to use boost, just write it without boost: [undirected adjacency-list](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e89f7e9f8025695d) or [undirected adjacency-matrix](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69aac9b52840396d) or even [directed adjacency-matrix](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fb8dea7936cace5)

Comment: @Monaphys in the part that describes it.

Comment: The difference between [a](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69aac9b52840396d) and [b](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1fb8dea7936cace5) is this: https://i.imgur.com/6BTaXYZ.png

Comment: I can not open the png file. In which line of the code difference between a and b enters?

Comment: But in all of your links, you are connecting vertices using  g.addEdge(j, i);  I need a solution in which you don't connect vertices in main by hand, instead, the code do that by knowing "directed" matrix which I have introduced in the question

Comment: Oh, huh you didn't introduce any matrix in the question code. If I understand correctly, now you just need to convert from the matrix to the adjacency-list. Well, here's my 2 cents: ***[integrating all 4 graph types](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f46648898a4484c0)***. You can freely **`convertGraph`** from any graph representation to another and `connectedComponents` works on each of them (with a sinlge implementation). The demo program even verifies that the matrix representation yields the same connected components as using the adjacency-list representation.

Comment: I have edited the code. Could you also edit your answer to find the number of groups and size of them in the code presented in the question?

Comment: I'm sorry I fail to complete your code promptly. I had to do the laundry first. Thank you for your patience. Here's the change: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33ab1d8878f27824. Please don't fire me. My family needs the money. As a bonus, consider this more convenient way to input the edges: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/011594a2f8d58c14

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem olved

Comment: In case you didn't really pick up on it, I did purposefully give somewhat advanced answers without explanation. I did so because it was so painfully clear that you are not interested in understanding how things work.Right now, I have the strong suspicion you didn't even write the code in your question, but found that somewhere. You probably thought you had 80% of the work done, but instead you had the new problem of transforming your matrix input into the adjacency list format for the code you found?

Comment: I hope you're not just going to turn this in as the solution for your assignment, without understanding it. It will probably be plenty clear someone else wrote the code. It's your own education, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the `DFSUtil` methord to return an `int` the specifies the number of nodes visited.

```
int Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[])
{
// Mark the current node as visited and print it
visited[v] = true;
int count  = 0;
cout << v << " ";

// Recur for all the vertices
// adjacent to this vertex
list<int>::iterator i;
for(i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
    if(!visited[*i])
      count += DFSUtil(*i, visited, count + 1);
    else 
      return 1;
return count;
}
```

And with some booking keeping we'll know know many groups and the size of each group from this

```
   // Method to print connected components in an
    // undirected graph
    void Graph::connectedComponents()
    {
    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for(int v = 0; v < V; v++)
        visited[v] = false;
    vector<pair<int,int>> groups;
    for (int v=0; v<V; v++)
    {
         if (visited[v] == false)
           {
            // print all reachable vertices
            // from v
            int groupSize = DFSUtil(v, visited);
            groups.push_back(make_pair(v, groupSize))
            cout << "\n";
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide a runnable answer which uses 'directed' matrix?